# Business Catalyst: Can I apply a template to an entire directory and override the default template?

Tags: templates, content-management-system, business-catalyst

I'm working in Business Catalyst on a website that I created a while back. A default template has been set for the entire website (this will apply to 404 pages, etc).

Recently I've created a new directory within the website that will be related to the main site, but the layout is completely different.

At first this didn't concern me, it's easy enough to just set the template as being my new template for each of the pages in the new website section. However, when I put some of the pages into a secure zone, the login page that you're redirected to uses the default template of the main website.

Can I apply a Business Catalyst template to the entire directory so that when I visit say:

http://mydomain.com/new/this_doesnt_exist.html

The template for my new layout will be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply a default template to all pages within a directory, you'll just need to go in to the pages inside that directory and set the template for them. Unless you have a *heap* of pages, not sure this is a big issue though.

Perhaps post a URL of what you're trying to achieve and I can understand better.

Also, have you checked out the [official BC forums](http://businesscatalyst.com/support/forums) - lots of people to help out over there too! :)

Comment: Just realized that you're talking about the template that wraps around your secure zone login page - makes sense now!

My suggestion is that you use some simple JS on your "Unauthorized access" system message layout to detect the URL the user is coming from (check for the directory you're referring to) and then push them over via a redirect to an appropriately styled, static page with the login form inserted (you can insert login forms using the Module Manager)

Comment: Actually, how would I apply that to a page that is dynamic? ie I don't have access to the HTML of it..?